# Spring Boot: Override yml list property

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

For my unit tests I'm trying to override the "property-sources[0]" element of my spring cloud azure configuration so that it is not used during unit tests.

But it seems that the changes done in my application-test.yaml file is not used for the list element and I don't know what the issue, or the correct way to do it, is.

The changes done to the spring.datasource is correctly applied (in memory database is started and the log states: The following 1 profile is active: "test") but the build fails. Because when starting the test, my application tries to connect with the Azure Key Vault defined in the application.yaml:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to configure KeyVault property source
...
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: my.vault.azure.net
```

Testclass (Kotlin):

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension::class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
internal class BrablTest {...}
```

application.yaml:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=my_db;applicationName=myApp;disableStatementPooling=false;enablePrepareOnFirstPreparedStatementCall=true;statementPoolingCacheSize=20
    username: my_user
    password:
    driver-class-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource
  cloud:
    azure:
      keyvault:
        secret:
          property-sources[0]:
            credential:
              managed-identity-enabled: true
            endpoint: https://my.vault.azure.net/
```

application-test.yaml:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
  cloud:
    azure:
      keyvault:
        secret:
          property-sources[0]:
            enabled: false
            endpoint: https://local.vault.azure.net/
```

Versions:

- Java 17.0.4
- Spring Boot v2.7.4
- Spring v5.3.23
- Spring Cloud Azure dependencies 4.4.0

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: AFAIN, indexed properties can not be overridden across property sources anymore. I'd suggest moving the property out of application.yml into one with a profile for prod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @spencergibb for pointing it out.
I've read the documentation again and it is written there, that because of the higher priority only the values from "application.yaml" are taken.

[Merging Complex Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.merging-complex-types)

> When a List is specified in multiple profiles, the one with the highest priority (and only that one) is used.

[Externalized Configuration (order)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config)

> Config data files are considered in the following order:
>
> 1. Application properties packaged inside your jar (application.properties and YAML variants).
> 2. Profile-specific application properties packaged inside your jar (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants).